# PHPUnit object cloned

Tags: phpunit, php-7.1

we're working on PHPunitizing our application with two scopes in mind: reduce regressions and bugs in releases.
The application apply an MVC pattern but with no Open Source framework: we're actually use a proprietary one with lots of components coming from symfony (goal is to port all to symfony sometime in the future).

Application has some design flaws so doesn't fit perfectly for Unit Testing. Anyway we've got a point where we can start and here comes some strage behaviours i can't solve.

All of our business methods rely on router object passed by Dependency injection at creation time.
Router exposes some methods to get and set variables like _SERVER, _GET, _POST that are cloned inside router itself (Use of global variable is prohibited by design).

In the following test i set SERVER and GET just before tested class instancing.. so i was expect to find their values correctly during test. 
Instead they are fully empty and, of course, test fail.

Any clue of what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
/**
  * Test external class with valid UUID
  * 
  */
public function testGetClassPermissionExternal() {
    $TEST_SERVER_DATA = array(
        'REQUEST_URI' => 'https://sviluppo.pardgroup.com/test',
        'SERVER_PORT' => 443,
        'SERVER_NAME' => 'sviluppo.pardgroup.com'
    );
    // Due to bad design superglobal $_SERVER need to be fullfilled.
    $_SERVER = $TEST_SERVER_DATA;
    $this->router->setSERVER($TEST_SERVER_DATA);

    $TEST_POST_DATA = array('uuid' => self::$UUID);
    $this->router->setGET($TEST_POST_DATA);

    $this->class = \permission::getInstace($this->router);

    $test_class = array("permissionTest/external");
    $this->assertFalse($this->invokeMethod($this->class, "getClassPermission", $test_class));
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you will need to look at backupGlobals

Comment: Your question is hard to answer given the information in your question. It looks like somewhere else that $_SERVER superglobal is set empty. But where one can only guess. What I do not understand is that for the router object if you inject those values, you should not need to rely on the superglobal any longer. It is likely worth to remove $_SERVER from you code to as little places as possible.